# SMTP not available due to a temporary reason

Tags: java, email, smtp, tls1.2

I'm trying to connect to a SMTP server using javax.mail api with TLS but I'm getting an error:

"javax.net.ssl.exception: Unrecognized ssl message, plaintext connection?"

The steps for the error are: 
.
.

1. Client send STARTTLS
2. Server answers: Go ahead with TLS
3. Client sends a reply containing binary data but in the end of the same message, is sending the name of the SMTP server as plain text too...
4. Server answers : "SMTP not available due to a temporary reason"
5. Client exits and prints the error: "javax.net.ssl.exception: Unrecognized ssl message, plaintext connection?"

I believe the error is related with sending the SMTP server name concatenated (as plain text) in the client hello message (step 3 above) but, any more thoughts on why this is happening?
The client Java properties are:

```
props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp-server-hostname");
props.put("mail.smtp.port", "25");
props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "false");
props.put("mail.transport.protocol", "smtp");
props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
props.put("mail.smtp.ssl.protocols", "TLSv1.2");
props.put("mail.debug", "true");
```

(The server is configured to accept TLS in port 25)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found what was the problem: I was using in my maven :

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
        <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
        <version>1.4</version>
</dependency>
```

instead of:

```
 <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.mail</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.mail</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.2</version>
</dependency>
```